# Laravel Eloquent - Combining queries to single one using relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a project where I'm using Laravel Eloquent to fetch all my data from my database.

I'm storing basketball clubs, teams and players in different tables.
Now I want to select all basketball players that belong to a team that belongs to a club.

I created a relation in the `Club` model:

```
public function basketballPlayers()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Basketball\BasketballPlayer','App\Models\Basketball\BasketballTeam','id','team_id');
    }
```

And a `user` relation in the `BasketballPlayer` model:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User','id','user_id');
    }
```

Now when I execute the following command, `DB::getQueryLog()` returns 3 Queries.

```
Club::findOrFail($club_id)->basketballPlayers()->with('user')->get();
```

But when I execute the following command without using relations, `DB::getQueryLog()` returns only 1 query.

```
$players = BasketballPlayer::Join('basketball_teams','basketball_teams.id','=','basketball_players.team_id')
            ->join('users','users.id','=','basketball_players.user_id')
            ->where('basketball_teams.club_id','=',$authUser->club_id)
            ->get(['basketball_players.*','users.firstname','users.lastname','basketball_teams.name']);
```

I don't need all the data from the club and the user (see `->get(...)` in the Join query).

Is it possible to achieve the same result like in the "long" manual Join-query using the much cleaner and simpler Eloquent relation approach?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can read less data using `with` (not all user columns as example) by this

```
Club::findOrFail($club_id)
    ->basketballPlayers()
    ->with('user:id,firstname,lastname')   // <- here is change
    ->get();
```

The `id` (and foreign keys) column is important. You should be also able to make nested `with` in following way (I write code from head - so please test it):

```
Club::findOrFail($club_id)
    ->with('BasketballPlayer:id,user_id')
    ->with('BasketballPlayer.user:id,firstname,lastname')   
    ->get();
```

Comment: but this still needs three queries. Isn't this a performance issue? The second query I created gets everything with one single query. Is it possible to get the same output using relations with a single query?

Comment: @Mike_NotGuilty I update answer, however as far I know it will be not easy to reduce number of queries using `with` - so this little improvement is all I can share with you

Comment: Thanks for your help. This does not improve the number of queries. So the only thing I can do is work with custom Join queries to keep the performance and queries  at a minimum level?

Comment: As far I know yes - however wait for others answers - maybe someone will find better way (including usage of external library)

Comment: You can use lazy eager loading with load() function. It will still use 3 queries but you can actually get the data only when you want. Its just a way to delay the query only when you need the items. But for the safe bet of performance, I too agree with Kamil that using join will give you one query. If you have indexes to keys set in MySQL, it will speed up even more